# What land destruction enabler was wrongfully banned in the early history of Magic: the Gathering?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, history

I once heard a story about a Land Destruction deck that dominated tournaments at some point in early Magic's history. The story as I remember it is that the deck ran heavy land destruction to deny resources to the opponent, and it won with another card, which I believe dealt damage based on lands destroyed.

The card in question was inevitably banned, and Mark Rosewater occasionally comments that it's not the card's fault the deck was winning, and Land Destruction in general should have been seen as the problem instead.

What is the name of the card that was banned this way?

Comment: You may find this question interesting. https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/28919/why-was-kird-ape-banned-in-very-first-extended-ban-list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Dingus Egg](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDingus%20Egg%5d) was banned once upon a time, and it does 2 damage to the land's controller when a land is put into the graveyard from play. A few of these do a lot of damage per land, I've seen it in a few land destruction decks over the years. It's not currently banned in any formats it would otherwise be legal in.

Comment: As a side note, I agree with MaRo, land destruction can get to be a big problem, thankfully it has slowed down over the years.

Comment: They really where clueless about bannings in the early days.

Comment: Then again that did share a format with both strip mine, sinkhole, and wasteland.

Comment: Strip mine was the one I was thinking of

Comment: @Segfault yes except the specific question asked for a card that "dealt damage based on lands destroyed." strip mine didn't to damage it just destroyed lands.

Comment: @NeilMeyer Clueless about banning in early days, now getting back to being clueless about design, there were years without a standard ban, now we're getting those regularly since Mindsculptor.

Comment: @NeilMeyer with strip mine and wasteland it's a double edged sword, sacrificing strip mine or wasteland to destroy an opponent land nets you both the same damage, both lands hit the graveyard, and you'd take the hit first (if losing that life would decide the game, or open you up to losing from burn spells cast in response)